# Spamicide field still visible

Tags: 7, advertising

To prevent spambot making fake user accounts I've installed Spamicide.

I've enabled the module Spamicide (7.x-1.0-beta3) and enabled the field for form_id user_register_form, filled in a Spamicide directory and chose a custom FORM FIELD NAME.

Now when creating a new account I still see a empty field with a description:
*"To prevent automated spam submissions leave this field empty"*. I was expecting that this was hidden by CSS?

Also the directory name I've setup can't be found, is it not created by itself?

The flooding of spambots creating fake accounts is stopped, but the empty field and belonging message looks stupid for real users.

Can you tell me if I did setup something wrong or if this could be an bug?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a bug. Simply hide it in your theme instead. Just try to use technique a bit less obvious than `display: none;` as many bots know it already. Note that newest version of Spamicide module (7.x-1.0-beta3 at the moment of posting) does not even provide CSS file. All it does is:

```
/**
 * #post_render callback on the spamicide field. This will wrap the field
 * in a div so it can be hidden with CSS.
 *
 */
function _spamicide_field_post_render($content, $element) {
    return '<div class="' . _spamicide_get_css_class($element['#name']) . '">' . $content . '</div>';
}
```

See line 81 of `spamicide.inc`.